# Exception from thread doesn't bubble up to main thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, exception

Here I start a task:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
    RefreshCache(crmClientInfo)).ContinueWith(
        previous => RefreshCacheExceptionHandling(previous.Exception),
        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted
    );
```

...and here is my worker:

```
public void RefreshCache(CrmClientInfo _crmClientInfo)
{
    AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();

    Timer timer = new Timer(10000);
    timer.Elapsed += delegate
    {
        throw new AggregateException("Timeout!");
    };
    timer.Start();

    OtherServices.RefreshCache(crmClientInfo);
    AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
}
```

If an exception occurs not in the timer definition but somewhere else, the exception bubbles up correctly to `RefreshCacheExceptionHandling()`. But if it fires from timer `(AgregateException("Timeout!");)` then the thread doesn't break. **Why?**

Comment: Proably because the timer runs on a separate thread...

Comment: Exceptions don't work that way. An exception can only propagate up the call chain. They don't go sideways.

Comment: However, I think it's possible to pass this exception to another thread if it is really needed. Not very simple, but could be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The System.Threading.Timer class makes callbacks on a ThreadPool
>   thread and does not use the event model at all.

Take a look at the documentation , here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdzx8wx8.aspx

Comment: @Igor System.Timers.Timer is just a wrapper around a System.Threading.Timer. If you never set a `SynchronizingObject` the callback is called on a ThreadPool thread. You should read the remarks section in the MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx Also, the page linked by animaonline clearly states "The Timer (link to System.Timers.Timer) class derives from Component, so it can be used with visual designers; it also raises events, but it raises them on a ThreadPool thread."